# Sending Arabic Text via Java Web Service

Tags: java, character-encoding, sms, arabic

I am getting special characters(?????) on my mobile when I send arabic text through JAVA Webservice. Below is the whay how I implemented.

1. Webservice Client and Test program is on my windows PC and I am running from Eclipse whose char set is ISO-8859-1.
2. In my Test Program I am encoding (using URLEncoder) the Arabic String to ISO-8859-6.
3. WebService Host is Installed on Linux server. Here I am converting the encoded string to bytes. Then I am forwading this request to java service over TCP IP. This service is responsible to send SMS.
4. In this Java service I am decoding with same encryption as above and posting to SMS provider.

#### Implementation

```
/**
 * Arabic Implementation is as below
 **/
String message= arabictext;
message=URLEncoder.encode(message,"ISO-8859-6");
sendMessage(message,uername,password); ///webservice call
```

#### Web Service Host coding:

```
sendMessage(p_message,username,password){
    byte[] request = message.getbytes();//tried by passing character set
    Tcserver.post(request);//posting the request to java client
}
```

Note: Both Webservice Host and java client are hosted on same physical server.

#### Java Client :

```
sendSMS(p_message){
    message =URLDecoder.decode(p_message,"ISO-8859-6");//send message to mobile provider.
    sendmessagetoProvider(message);
}
```

when I ran TCPViewer on my PC I am seeing special characters. Any idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: Does the `sendmessagetoProvider` support the exact characters you give as an argument in `message`?

Comment: Yes. I my earlier posting I missed to add one more point. I tried to post the arabic message from HTML page to java client direclty. I have one admin application running on my local desktop(hosted on Tomcat). In this case I am getting perfect arabic text on my mobile. Hence I am sure my java client Implementaion has no issues. I guess its some thing related to webservice call. I tried to call the webservice from other PC..still same Issue

Comment: `sendMessage` cannot compile.

Comment: andy,ca you brief what you are telling..

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is somewhere into your `sendmessagetoProvider` as well as in usage for `URLEncoder` and `URLDecoder`.

When you are sending message you probably have to encode it. You are calling `decode` at client side instead. BTW IMHO this is the reason for "special characters" you receive.

So, first take a look on your API specification. What is method `sendmessagetoProvider` expecting? Probably you do not have to encode the string as URL? Probably it just supports Unicode or you have to provide the encoding when you are calling client? Then fix you code accordingly.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Alex,Thanks for reply. I my earlier posting I missed to add one more point. I tried to post the arabic message from HTML page to java client direclty. I have one admin application running on my local desktop(hosted on Tomcat). In this case I am getting perfect arabic text on my mobile. Hence I am sure my java client Implementaion has no issues. I guess its some thing related to webservice call. I tried to call the webservice from other PC..still same Issue.